# Extjs How to make Grid Column Header Menu options persist in Cookies (Stateful)

Tags: extjs, cookies, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

Using Sencha Architect Version 3.0.2

ExtJS 4.1

I am trying to make the selections in the Grid column headers stateful and save them in  a cookie.
What I am after is the Columns menu that further dropdowns to list the columns in the grid with a Checkbox besides it. Selecting/Un-selecting this box will unhide/hide the respective column.

I want to save this setting so that next time the user loads the grid, a column that is unselected before is hidden and does not appear (until obviously cookies are cleared).

[Example Fiddle Located here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/a6p)

Following is the menu I am talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set stateProvider and make the grid [stateful](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-stateful):true with [stateId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-stateId), fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/a6s

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have those properties already set in my code. The state is saved for Asc or Desc order of columns, but not for hiding/shwing columns. Does using Reconfigure make any difference?? Because I am using grid.reconfigure(store, columns) based on my clients config setup. @newmount

Comment: reconfiguring columns will make it visible unless you pass hidden:true in the column config..

Comment: ya that's correct, but to determine whether to make it hidden or not I need to retrieve the state which I can see is always the default (not hidden). @newmount